# My Firebase app doesn't store current user data locally

Tags: javascript, reactjs, firebase, firebase-authentication

After logging into my Firebase application, the user logs in, but when it renews, the current user's information is deleted. `return firebase.auth().setPersistence(firebase.auth.Auth.Persistence.LOCAL).then(...)` It's still the same for me using the code. My code is here:

```
class LogIn extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.app = !firebase.apps.length ? firebase.initializeApp(CONFIG) : firebase.app();
    this.user = firebase.auth().currentUser;
}

render() {
  function SignIn() {
    return firebase.auth().setPersistence(firebase.auth.Auth.Persistence.LOCAL)
    .then(function() {
      return firebase.auth().signInWithEmailAndPassword(document.getElementById("email").value, document.getElementById("password").value)
      .then((user) => {
        if (firebase.auth().currentUser) {
          document.getElementById("x").innerHTML = firebase.auth().currentUser.email;
        }
      }) 
    })
  }

  return (
   <div>
      Login<br /><br />
      <div>
        Username<br />
        <input id="email" type="text" autoComplete="new-password" />
      </div>
      <div style={{ marginTop: 10 }}>
        Password<br />
        <input id="password" type="password" autoComplete="new-password" />
      </div>
      <input type="submit" onClick={SignIn}/>
   </div>
  );
}};
```

Comment: It's not clear what you mean by "when it renews" and "the current user's information is deleted".  Please edit the question to explain in more detail what you are doing and observing that's different than what you expect.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you reload the page Firebase automatically tries to refresh the user's authentication state. But since this requires a call to the server it takes some time, and for that reason the user is initially set to null.

To pick up when Firebase has finished refreshing the user's authentication state, use an auth state listener as shown in the first sample in the documentation on [getting the current user](https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/web/manage-users#get_the_currently_signed-in_user):

> ```
> firebase.auth().onAuthStateChanged(function(user) {
>  if (user) {
>    // User is signed in.
>  } else {
>    // No user is signed in.
>  }
> });
> ```